# Unable to import rpy2, VSCode in WSL windows subsytem for linux

Tags: python, rpy2

Looking for help on using rpy2 in python script with vscode from WSL. I can't get the import to work.

If i try to run the following code:

```
import rpy2

print(rpy2.__version__)
```

I get the following AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'rpy2' has no attribute '__version__' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

If I try to `import rpy2.rpackages`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2.rpackages'; 'rpy2' is not a package
```

I have successfully installed rpy2 through the bash terminal on VSCode with pip as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no module or sub-package `rpackages` in rpy2, so the error message when trying to import it is expected.

The error about a circular a partially initialized module is surprising. Do you happen to have a directory called `rpy2` where you are running this from? Python would try to import that directory.

Comment: Yikes! I had a python script called rpy2.py ... embarrassing question ... Thanks for solving!!